# Vim not setting correct file type for jinja files

Tags: filetype

Whenever I create html file with `jinja` code from terminal either using shell commands or directly using `vim`, the file type is always set to `html` and not `jinja.html`, which causes number of issues like `jinja` files not being syntax highlighted, snippets do not show up in completion popups.

I am using `Glench/Vim-Jinja2-Syntax` for jinja syntax highlighting. I do understand this plugin might be looking for certain keywords in the file to associate the file as `jinja.html` file. Even if I create a file like below in `Vim`, save it , close it with `:wq` and then open it again, still the file type is `html` only.

```
{%  extends "base.html" %}

{% block body %}

{% endblock %}
```

This is what `set filetype?` reports `filetype=html` .

However if I create the same file with some IDE like `PyCharm` or `VsCode` this does not happen, and after that if I open the file in `Vim`, then it sets the correct file type as `jinja.html`. My guess is `PyCharm` and `VsCode` might be adding some metadata to the file while creating the file which Vim is not doing when the file is created by Vim but I am not sure about this..

Another weird thing that I noticed, say I create a file named `dummy.html` with above `jinja` code with `Vim` and then save+close it, obviously `Vim` isn't setting the correct file type for it. Now the weird, even if I delete this file and then recreate it in `PyCharm` with same name i.e. `dummy.html` and load in `Vim` , `Vim` fails to set the correct file type.

I tested this multiple file names, means I created the file in `Vim` and then delete it and then create the file with same name in `PyCharm` and `Vim` does not set the file type. However if I use a new name while creating the file in `PyCharm`, a name which I haven't used while creating file with `Vim` , then `Vim` file sets the file type correctly to `jinja.html`.

So can anyone please help me how can I fix this. I apologize if the issue description is bit confusing but this issue is so weird that honestly I am not sure how to better the description.

Comment: @Ralf just updated the question to contain lot more detail

Comment: I installed the `Glench/Vim-Jinja2-Syntax` plugin and created your example file. At first it was detected as `html`, as it has no content. After writing and `:e!` or on reopen Vim, it was detected as `jinja.html` and the filetype was correct. Tested on Vim 8.1.885 on Linux. I would recommend to strip down your Vim setup to only contain `Vim-Jinja2-Syntax` and test again.

Answer (score 1):

Update:

What file type plugin are you using for Jinja? Vim doesn't ship with one so you must have installed it. Looking into it will probably give you some pointers. Also, there are several plugins, so you could try another one.

=====

If there is a difference depending on how the file is created, the file type recognition may be dependent on whether or not a byte order mark (BOM) is present (there is probably no BOM in files created on the terminal).

So a first workaround might be to add a BOM (or remove it if present) for offending files:

`:set invbomb`

You may have to save and re-read the file to refresh syntax highlighting:

`:w | e`

I'm afraid I have no immediate idea *why* the file type recognition might be BOM-dependent and how to remedy that.

Comment: Yeah, It could be due to that only, that was my guess that Pycharm or vscode might be adding some metadata to the file while creating which Vim is not doing. Also I tried setting `invbomb` and then reloading the file but it didn't work.